# Create a directory in the internal memory and save files

Tags: android, file

This question might a duplicated one. I am sorry for it. I have gone through a number of similar posts but could not get it done in my work.

In my application, I want to store the Json data in .txt files and store them in a specific folder in the Internal memory. Or storing the files directly in the Android/data folder would also be okay.

I used the following codes to do so but I am not able to find the files stored as I wanted. Can anyone tell me what is teh problem with my code and How can i correct it??

```
String fname, fcontent;
Context context;
ProgressDialog pDialog;

public SaveIntoFile(String fileName, String jsonStr, Context context, ProgressDialog pDialog) {
    this.fname = fileName;
    this.context = context;
    this.fcontent = jsonStr;
    this.pDialog = pDialog;
}

public void write() {
    try {

        File mydir = context.getDir("NepalJapan", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        File file = new File(mydir, fname+".txt");

        if (file.exists())
            file.delete();
        // If file does not exists, then create it
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write(fcontent);
        bw.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}

public String read() throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String response = null;

    StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();

    File mydir = context.getDir("NepalJapan", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    File file = new File(mydir, fname+".txt");

    if (!file.exists()) {

        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();

        return null;
    } else {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line = "";
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            output.append(line + "\n");
        }
        response = output.toString();

        br.close();

        return response;
    }

}
```

Comment: does it show errors? in logcat maybe

Comment: Have you given read/write permission in Manifest file?

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira It shows no error in the logcat. The app runs well but does not stores the files.

Comment: @sUndeep This code is for read/write in the internal memory. Do we need to give permission in the menifest??

Comment: @sUndeep Yes, I have already given such permission in the menifest. But that is for external storage, isn't it??

Comment: ok. Let me check the code

Comment: how did you call the object?are you already set `String fname, fcontent;
Context context;` ?

Comment: Wrong. You do not need these EXTERNAL permissions for accessing INTERNAL memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the code snippet to place a txt file in internal memory. To see the file. you have to run your test app in emulator and then goto DDMS -> File Explorer -> app_NepalJapan -> hello.txt

```
public static String write(Context context, String strfilename) {

        String internalMemoryPath = "";

        try {

            File InternalMemoryRoot = context.getDir("NepalJapan", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            final File folderPath = new File(InternalMemoryRoot+"");

            Log.v("filePath","filePath: "+folderPath);

            if(!folderPath.exists() && !folderPath.isDirectory()){
                folderPath.mkdirs();
            }

            String filePath = folderPath +"/"+ strfilename;
            Log.v("filePath","filePath: "+filePath);



            File file = new File(filePath);
            FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);

            // create a buffer...
            byte[] buffer = new byte[16384];
            int bufferLength = 1; 
            fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
            fileOutput.close();

            internalMemoryPath = filePath;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return internalMemoryPath;
    }
```

Call method in your activity: `YourStaticUtilClass.write(context, "hello.txt");`

If you still find any difficulty, then let me know.